# Redirect and append GET-Parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having trouble with redirecting from one URL to another, while appending one GET-parameter to the NEW URL.

The first time (from root of old domain to root of new domain) works perfectly fine. After (further down in the .htaccess this one case) the GET-parameter appears randomly in the middle of the new url.

Obviously that leads to some nasty 404 situations...

```
RewiriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / https://foo.bar?redirect=1
Redirect 301 /foo/bar/ https://foo.bar/foo/bar?redirect=1
```

To give further information:

The idea is to redirect inklusive this parameter, to trigger a popup, giving information about the recent redirect so the user doesn't lose his confidence about the visit of *foo.bar*.

The first redirect will result in just the right way, it works perfectly.
The second thou, turns out like:

https://foo.bar/foo/?redirect=1bar/

Please and Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your rules work fine as you configure them , why ?

With `mod_alias` `redirect` and this part

```
Redirect 301 / https://foo.bar?redirect=1
```

Will match `/` & `/foo/` & `/foo/bar/` and so on , so the second rule will not work at all because of every request being captured by firrt rule ,and the result of redirecting `/foo/bar/` with first rule is `foo/bar?redirect=1foo/bar/` because with redirect every things after match will be appending to new target.

To avoid that use `RedirectMatch`

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /?$ https://foo.bar/foo/bar?redirect=1
RedirectMatch 301 /foo/bar/ https://foo.bar/foo/bar?redirect=1
```

By this way with regex , you will be able to match against root only by first rule then against `/foo/bar/` by second rule.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test